# EMBEDDING (not dynamically linking) private framework with Xcode 5

Tags: frameworks, xcode5, embed

The directions for doing this on Apple's developer site

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880-BAJJBIEF

are for Xcode 2.4. At least they made that clear. The best info I have found is at

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1209938

but for this guy, "private" does not seem to mean "embedded" because the author still has you linking dynamically. I want to EMBED the framework. Any tips for modern Xcode?

Or will I just have to use static linking to get what I want? (Which is a single distributable executable.)

Comment: Workspaces could be the way to go? Haven't used one yet.